# Connect a slider to a list, marking a certain value

Tags: javascript, slider

I want to implement a feature that enables the user to drag a slider that is connected to a  list with values. The value closest to the slider bar will become "active" as the user drags it, as illustrated in the example image -

http://staffanestberg.com/example.png

I've looked into the jQuery UI Slider plugin but from what I understand it can't be tied to such a list. Not sure where to start really. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could just create a Slider with the appropriate min / max range, and a separate list of values. Using the Slider's `slide` event, you can get the value whenever the user drags the slider, determine which of the values is closest, and highlight the relevant list item.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d3zqY/1/

The first bit simply gets a list of `li` elements, and an array of values inside them. Then the `onslide` function gets called, passing in a value. There's a bit of maths to determine the closest number, then a bit of jQuery to apply a class to the relevant item.

So all that's left is to hook this function up to your slider.

```
var s = $('#slider');
s.slider({
    min:10000,
    max:1000000,
    slide:function(){
        onslide(s.value());
        }
    });
```

(BTW from the users' point of view I'd also expect to be able to click the value and the slider to adjust automatically.)